# React Native Axios Display Image from API response

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, axios, display

I've been trying with apisauce, now with axios. I have a backend that provides me with the image directly through an API. I can see it in Postman and I can see the "code" of the image, but I can't display it using the `<Image>` component in RN. This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const BlogEscolar = () => {
...
  const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://x.x.x.x:5001/api/FTPService/download",
          {
            params: { fileName: "image.png" },
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          }
        );
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log(response);** --> the response its ok**
          setImagePath(response);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching image:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } ;

    fetchImage();
  }, []);

...

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={{ uri: `${imagePath.request._response}` }} **--> ?? this is a laaaarge string**
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
  image: {
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 37.5,
  },
});

export default BlogEscolar;
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.